# scheduled task returns error 0xff despite success

Tags: windows, scheduled-task, batch-file

I have a scheduled task that runs a batch file, and even though I can see the results of it completing successfully, according to the task scheduler it fails with error **0xff**, every time.

I have other batch files scheduled that also complete successfully and return **0x0** as they should.  The only difference I can see between these files is that the working ones end with:

```
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
    ("notify me" script here)
)
```

whereas the broken one ends with:

```
IF %2==something (
    (run a program here)
    IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
        (same "notify me" script here)
    )
)
```

Does an IF block return **0xff** if false or something?  What's the deal?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The syntax you're looking for is:

```
IF "%2"=="SOMETHING" (
```

When %2 is empty, the line you have becomes:

```
IF ==SOMETHING (
```

That's invalid syntax. Putting the quotes in it makes it:

```
IF ""=="SOMETHING" (
```

That's valid.

Comment: Remember! exit 0xFF means "syntax error in batch file"!

Answer (score 0):

After some testing, I figured out that IF blocks are okay, they don't seem to change the error level, but what was messing it up was the "%2==something"--the times that were failing, there was no second parameter being passed to the batch file.  So I'm not sure how to "safely" test for whether a parameter exists (i.e., without it erroring out 0xff when it's not there) except maybe to have yet another IF ERRORLEVEL after that.  But anyway, I just changed the scheduled task so it will always have a second parameter (whether it's "something" or not) and it seems to return 0x0 as it should now.